# discord.py - How do i send a message on a just created channel?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am building a ticket bot, it creates a channel every time someone reacts a message in the "ticket" category, how to get the channel obj so the bot can send a message there?

I have this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    client.get_channel(payload.message_id)
    msg = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
    f = open("ticket_nums.txt", "w+")
    overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        payload.member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
    }
    if True: #r_msg_id == "720708414107287724": commented out because it doesn't work idk why
        if not payload.user_id == "718528256365559829":
            await msg.remove_reaction("\U0001f4e8", discord.Object(id=user_id))
            await client.get_channel(719621258106372219).create_text_channel(r"ticket#" , overwrites=overwrites)
```

also while opening the ticket_nums file, which should contain the ticket count, it keeps me giving me this error: *(It's giving it every time I try to open a file)*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\giaco\Desktop\Bot\Discord Bot\bot_discord.py", line 216, in on_raw_reaction_add
    f = open("ticket_nums.txt", "w+")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'ticket_nums.txt'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a channel, it returns the channel object back. Thanks to this, you can put it into a variable and then `send()` it:

```py
channel = await category.create_text_channel(...)
await channel.send("Hey! I just created this channel!")
```

As for your `Permission denied` error, I suspect you need elevated permissions on your account. To let the program have the necessary permissions, you can run whatever IDE you're using as administrator:

Right-click > Run as administrator > Allow > Run your script

---

**References:**

- [`create_text_channel()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_text_channel) - Specifically, `Return type`:
  [image]
- [`abc.Messageable`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable)
- [`Messageable.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.send)

Comment: With the code you already had, you only had to write one line from my answer. If you added in both of the lines I added, it will create two channels. Just add `channel = ` in front of your `await category.create_text_channel(...` and it'll work as you wish. Either that, or you have two instances of your bot running.

Comment: i have this and it's creating 2 channels https://pastebin.com/4VmCT0BY

Comment: Then I suspect you have two bot instances running. If you're not using an IDE like PyCharm where you can easily stop a script (or if you can't find it in task manager), then you might need to restart your PC. (Just an FYI, the variable name you gave the channel `new_ticket = ` doesn't match your `await new_channel.send(...)`).

Comment: you were right, i use atom and i had two instances running, thx for your help, i also noticed the `new_channel` error, thx

Comment: just another thing... i have this: https://pastebin.com/ppyvqdHv and gives me this error: `await new_ticket_obj.channel.say(membertag, embed=embed)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'channel'`

Comment: `get_channel()` [takes an ID](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel), and you're giving it a channel object. Besides, `new_ticket_obj` ***is*** the channel object, so you don't need to use `get_channe()`. Just `await new_ticket_obj.say(....)` will suffice.

Comment: ok but anyway it's giving me this error:
```await new_ticket.channel.say(membertag, embed=embed)
AttributeError: 'TextChannel' object has no attribute 'channel'
```

Comment: You don't need `.channel` after `new_ticket` because `new_ticket` is the channel. It has the `send()` coroutine. Just `await new_ticket.send(...)` will suffice. See [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.send).

Comment: ok thanks, but why dosent send also the `membertag`? _(It's defined)_

Comment: You can send the member tag if you want to, I was just leaving the brackets open to show the syntax of the coroutine. `await new_ticket.send(membertag, embed=embed)` will still work.

Comment: i was getting the member tag (For example: crashback#1484) with `payload.member.id` but dosent work, neither with `payload.member_nick` it's working, how to do it?

Comment: Sorry, this isn't a place for spoonfeeding, I've done enough as it is - I'd recommend looking at recent rewrite tutorials and looking at the rewrite docs (v1.x). (Hint, it's called a discriminator). Use `ctrl + f` to search for keywords in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

For the sending a message in a newly created channel, you can set a variable when you create the channel.

```
ticket_channel = await category.create_text_channel(r"ticket#" , overwrites=overwrites)
```

Then you could use the normal `TextChannel.send()` method.